# Why content does not center for width in terms of percentage

Tags: html, css

Why does the content does not center when I provide width in terms of  `%` instead of `px`

```css
    .content-container{
        width : 100%;
        margin:0 auto;
        padding: 80px 0 0 0;
        position: relative;
        display: block;
    }

    .content-container2{
        width : 100px;
        margin:0 auto;
        padding: 80px 0 0 0;
        position: relative;
        display: block;
    }
```

```html
<div class='content-container'>
  <div style="float:left;">Hello there</div>  
</div>

<div class='content-container2'>
  <div style="float:left;">Hello there</div>  
</div>
```

I want to the content to center for width=100%. Thanks in advance.

Comment: 100% wide element fills the entire width of the container so centering such element doesn't make much sense. What kind of effect are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Juhana, I am trying to build a mobile based web app for which I require to set the width to 100%. But for the desktop it was 1000px for which the centering worked.

Comment: Have you considered `max-width:1000px` instead?

Comment: @Juhana I want the div to cover up the entire device width in mobile. Max-width does not achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using media-queries?

Take a look at CSS3 [media queries](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp).

They are exactly what you need. All you need to do is specify some maximum or minimum screen dimensions in your case for each media-query. This way, you can design how your site looks on mobile devices, tablets, computers, etc. and they need not all be the same!

Using media-query, you can set the width to 100% for mobile devices and set the width to say 50% and center it on desktop computers.

Something that looks good on a big screen like that of a computer need not necessarily look good on a mobile device but using media query, you can design separate versions for both devices!

For example, you execute some CSS only for desktop computers using `min-width`

```
@media screen and (min-width: 800px) { /*The following CSS runs only for displays with a width (in pixels) of more than 800px*/
    body {
        background-color: lightblue;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) { /*The following CSS runs only for displays with a width (in pixels) of less than 800px*/
    body {
        background-color: yellow;
    }
}
```

This way, your webpage looks different on desktop computers and looks different on mobile devices and tablets.

Also, see [this](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) great link.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new class to your stylesheet and assign this class to **content-container**

```
.center {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -25%;
  margin-top: -25%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 40%;
  height: 50%;
}

<div class='content-container center'>
  <div style="float:left;">Hello there</div>  
</div>

<div class='content-container2'>
  <div style="float:left;">Hello there</div>  
</div>
```

Here's a live example

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ht64g203/)